# using .delegate function in slide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, delegates, slideshow

I have a script that runs a slideshow for my page. I'm trying to use `.delegate()` to insert a new set of images shown within the slideshow including its thumbnails. I'm using a `.load()` function to load an external `<div>` to replace some HTML within the active page. I also have buttons with IDs, (`#kick1`, `#kwick2`, etc.) that determine what set of slide show is loaded.

```
 jQuery("#kwick2").click(function () {
     jQuery("body").delegate('#slideshow', 'click', function() {
         jQuery('#slideshow').load('/design.html #design');      
     )};
 )};
```

Pretty sure the syntax is all wrong. Can someone help me?

The `#slideshow` `div` is something I created to contain some other `div`s directly 
effected by the slideshow script.  Within `div` ID `#slideshow` are

`<div class="main_image">`, `<div class="desc">` and `<div class="image_thumb">`.

These are being replaced directly when you click a KWICK button, they are all pretty much self explanatory, image thumb has and unordered list with image links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not re-deligate every time you click the button. You are doing the wrong.

Instead what you should have is something like:

```
var foobar = (function () {

   var func , mod1 , mod2;
   mod1 = function () {
      /* do something in state 1 */
   };
   mod2 = function () {
     /* do something in state 2 */
   };

   return {
      state: function (e) {
         switch (this.id){
            case 'kwick1':
               func = mod1;
               break;
            case 'kwick2':
               func = mod2;
               break;
         }
      },
      callback: function (e) {
         func.call();
      }
   }
})();

jQuery("#kwick1").click( foobar.state ); // and you really should delegate this
jQuery("#kwick2").click( foobar.state );
jQuery("body").delegate('#slideshow','click', foobar.callback);
```

Or something similar to this ..

And **no , i did not test this code**. It is written to explain the concept, not to spoon-feed people.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i have understood the question well, anyway you have to specify what event you are delegating

```
 jQuery("#kwick2").click(function () {
 jQuery("body").delegate('#slideshow',"click", function(){
    jQuery('#slideshow').load('/design.html #design');      
    )};
 )};
```

[`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: but its not the click its the whole script thats not applying to the new content inserted, check this link http://hovaness.com/work/ and see what i mean, the page on load is with the script working, then when you click design the new photos load but no effects and no description